# Implementing a volume graph on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-graphics

I'm trying to implement a graph (UIView) like this:

[image: GRAPH IMAGE LINK]

My current approach is to draw the rounded rects with **UIBezierPath** inside *drawRect*, store a pointer to every path in a private **NSMutableArray** and in my View Controller send a message to update the graph with the new value. (https://gist.github.com/gverri/f238ad17f90013bfc832)

But somehow I can't send a message to my view to change the colors of the paths.

.

I'm still a relative beginner and I'm sure I'm trying to reinvent the wheel somehow. Or just missing something obvious.

Should I redraw the graph at every update (1s ~ 2s)?! Should I use a special framework to do this?

## Edit:

After digging a little I found out that I can't save a pointer to a path. After `drawRect` my pointers disappear from the array.

It seems I would need to use Core Graphics do make it work with this approach.

Is there an easier alternative?

Comment: How are you trying to send that message? Show the code you've tried.

Comment: @rdelmar Here's the code: https://gist.github.com/gverri/f238ad17f90013bfc832

Do I need to call drawRect again?

Comment: I don't see anything in that code that sets the color to a darker color. I'm not sure this structure is the best way to go, but it depends on how your data is structured that you use to color the cells. I think I would make each column a single custom view with 7 subviews (rounded rectangles), and set the background color of those subviews with a method like setNumberOfDarkViews:(NSInteger) num. Then you could let the custom view color its own subviews.

Comment: Wouldn't that be to expensive? We're talking about 150+ subviews changing background color every 1~2s.

Comment: I made a little test app, and it seemed to work ok updating the values every 0.2 seconds (I was passing in random numbers for the number of darker cells in each column). You would have to profile both ways in instruments to see which way is faster.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and I'll let you know if it performed well. Any tips on how to profile it? I've never really done it before.

Comment: No, I don't really have much experience with using Instruments that way. I'll post my test app so you can see how I did it.

Comment: You can absolutely save pointers to UIBezierPath's. I've done it in several projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a test app that uses a column view with 7 rounded rect subviews to implement the graph. Here's the ColumnView class (a subview of UIView),

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray new];
        _offColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:238/255.0 green:230/255.0 blue:238/255.0 alpha:1];
        _onColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:154/255.0 green:102/255.0 blue:155/255.0 alpha:1];
        for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
            UIView *roundRect = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, i*34, frame.size.width -2, (frame.size.height/7) - 4)];
            roundRect.backgroundColor = _offColor;
            roundRect.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
            [temp insertObject:roundRect atIndex:0];
            [self addSubview:roundRect];
        }
        _columns = [NSArray arrayWithArray:temp];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)setNumberOfDarkRects:(NSInteger) num {
    [self.columns enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *sub, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if (idx + 1 <= num) {
            sub.backgroundColor = self.onColor;
        }else{
            sub.backgroundColor = self.offColor;
        }

    }];
}
```

This is how I create the grid, and test updating the columns,

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *columns;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.columns = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i=0; i<21; i++) {
       ColumnView *column = [[ColumnView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * 22 + 10, 50, 22, 240)];
        [self.view addSubview:column];
        [self.columns addObject:column];
    }
    [self performSelector:@selector(doRandomColoring) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
}


-(void)doRandomColoring {
    for (ColumnView *col in self.columns) {
        [col setNumberOfDarkRects:arc4random_uniform(8)];
    }
    [self performSelector:@selector(doRandomColoring) withObject:nil afterDelay:.2];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It seems to work. I'll try to profile it later.